# vb.net access the streamreader.readline which is currently looping

Tags: vb.net

In C#, it seems the following method works which will allow you to 
call Streamreader.readline() and then access that very same line in the next loop.

```
   string line;
    double score = 0;
    count = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        score += double.Parse (line);
        count++;
    }
    averageScore = (double)inValue / count;
```

This does not work in vb.net though, even with all the converters which I tried.

this one completely bombs out and throws "page not found"
http://converter.telerik.com/

this one:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=3356dd81-818a-43d1-8c23-be584e40d15e
results in :

```
Dim line As String
Dim score As Double = 0
count = 0
While (InlineAssignHelper(line, sr.ReadLine())) IsNot Nothing
    score += Double.Parse(line)
    count += 1
End While
averageScore = CDbl(inValue) / count
```

where InlineAssignHelper is something I dont have.

Comment: Are you reading it from a file? Do you have the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the filename, instead of just a stream, you can use `System.IO.File.ReadLines` for the neatest way:

```
Dim score As Double = 0
count = 0

For Each line In File.ReadLines(filename)
    score += Double.Parse(sr.ReadLine())
    count += 1
Next

averageScore = CDbl(inValue) / count
```

Or use LINQ:

```
Dim averageScore = File.ReadLines(filename).Average(AddressOf Double.Parse)
```

Comment: I think you want `Average` instead of `Sum` in your LINQ example :-)

Comment: Now let us get rid of that silly `Select` and just use `File.ReadLines(filename).Average(Function(x) Double.Parse(x))` and et voilà: LINQ at it's best :-)

Comment: @Mr.Steak: Thanks again, didn't know you could do that. I should probably go get Visual Studio back, huh? (P.S. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13088838/revisions)

Comment: Or just LINQPad. Sadly, I think `Average(AddressOf Double.Parse)` won't work, since this would be ambiguous between `Average(...) As Decimal` and `Average(...) As Decimal?`

Comment: Nonetheless, I like the `sr.BaseStream.Position < sr.BaseStream.Length` idea.

Comment: @Mr.Steak: `Double.Parse` will only return a `Double` and take a `String`; I can't see how it's ambiguous...

Comment: There are severe problems with this code.  It assumes that the base stream provides an implementation for the Position and Length properties.  That's not generally the case, a NetworkStream is a good example.  A fatal bug is that StreamReader has its own buffer.  Which will move BaseStream.Position to the end before the StreamReader has read all the text.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yep, this solution only applies if it's a file. And thank you, I didn't realize that `StreamReader` had a buffer; I'll just keep the LINQ one, then.

Comment: So... downvote reason, anyone? (Or is this just another one of those drive-by, no-reason-but-because-I-hate you ones? I get that a lot :-])

Answer (score 0):

Use a Do-Loop with an exit statement, like this:

```
    Do
        Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
        If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        score += Double.Parse(line)
        count += 1
    Loop
```

Do note the advantage of doing it this way over the accepted answer, it is very lean on memory usage and doesn't require the entire file to fit in memory.